# Responsive Design Testing using IFrames facing problems with IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, responsive-design

I am trying to create a page which accepts URL of the website and shows me all the display sizes horizontally.

something like this : http://dfcb.github.com/Responsivator/
or 
something like this : http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

In both the websites they are using iframes to load content in the specified width and then they are playing with width and height for different devices, it works well in all browsers apart from IE7 and IE8 I am wondering how to make it work on IE 7 and 8. There should be some way or other.

I read somewhere that http://www.ehow.com/how_8123203_use-iframes-ie8.html you can use P3P headers but I am not sure.

language is not an issue. but I just want it to be working on every browser.
I have developed a test page and kept it online : http://sentimentanalysis.comeze.com/responsiate/

if you see closely it works fine on chrome, ff, IE 9 but works pretty weird on IE7 and 8, how to make it look same? Is it possible?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Havent seen the links but why dont you just use iframes of different widths and then load the contrnt in each one?

Comment: yes, i am doing the exact same thing but it does not work in ie7 and ie8, in a way which works in ie9 or chrome or ff

Comment: I dont have the browsers but iframes should work. Design might differ of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Responsive design doesn't work in IE7 and 8.

Using methods like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){}
```

do not working in IE7 or IE8, the only way around this is the client side Chrome frame.

### Mobile headers (not responsive media queries)

You can send pretend mobile headers but that's about it. This would require a lot of messing about to fool the server into thinking you are on a mobile device, but it will take a lot of doing. Your server will have to request the page and all of it's assets (images, styles and scripts) and it won't show the true responsive design of the site: only the full mobile site if the target has one.

Comment: but in my case user might not have chrome frame plugin, can u give me some alternative by which I can make it work on IE 7 and 8?

Comment: No, sorry. The media queries simply do not work in IE7 and IE8. They are part of the CSS3 spec of which both IE7 and IE8 do not adhere too. There is no way of doing this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I will get back to you if I get something else on this one.

Comment: Updated the answer, please mark as the answer if you are happy with it.